# Write contents of static Object to disk at the end of the program

Tags: java

Is there a reliable way to write the contents of a static object to disk when the program ends?

At the moment, I call a `persist()` method on the static object at the end of each main() method that uses the static object. I wonder whether this can be done automatically.

Comment: What's a "static object"?

Comment: More concretely, I could have a public static myStoredClass which should be written to a file by myStoredClass.persist() at the end of the program (to read it back for all subsequent runs of different main methods).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754263/how-to-ensure-a-piece-of-code-is-run-before-exiting-a-java-application is a very similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a shutdown hook, which will ensure that your code is executed when the JVM is exiting gracefully (not forcibly killed).

For more information, check the accepted answer here: [Useful example of a shutdown hook in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java)

A howto can be found here: http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.co.za/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html